# Javascript event listener on a checkbox

Tags: javascript, forms, loops, addeventlistener

I'm trying to hide/show checkboxes based on a button click('send email' or 'cancel'). The button hide show works, but I also added an event listener to the checkboxes to change the button text to 'confirm' if any check box was active. It seems there's a delay in when a checkbox registers as 'checked' and I can't think of or find a better way to check it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
var checker = document.getElementById("emailer"); 
var radios = document.querySelectorAll(".radioEmail+label"); 

for (var i=0; i<radios.length; i++){
  radios[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    var checkingChecks = document.querySelectorAll(".radioEmail:checked").length;
    if (checkingChecks > 0) {
      document.getElementById("emailer").className="confirm";
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("emailer").className="cancel"
    } 
  }
)};   
 
 
document.getElementById("emailer").addEventListener('click', function(){ 
  if (checker.getAttribute('class')=='emailer'){ 
      checker.className = "cancel"; 
    for(var i = 0;radios.length>i;i++) {
      radios[i].style.display="inline-block"
    }  
  } 
  else if (checker.getAttribute('class')=='cancel') {
    for(var i = 0;radios.length>i;i++) { 
      radios[i].style.display="none"
    }
    checker.className="emailer";
  }   
});
```

```css
  input[type=checkbox].radioEmail + label{display:none}
.emailer:after{content:"Send Mass Email";} 
  .confirm:after{content:"confirm"} 
  .cancel:after{content:"cancel"} 
input[type=checkbox] + label{
  cursor:pointer;
  width       : 1em;
  font-size   : 0.875em;
  line-height : 1em;
  color       : white;
  text-align  : center;
  font-weight : bold;
  height           : 1em;
  margin           : 0.25em 0.5em 0.25em 0.25em;
  border           : 0.0625em solid #000066;
  border-radius    : 0.25em;
  background       : white;
  vertical-align   : bottom;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition:  ease-in-out 0.3s;}
  input[type=checkbox].radioEmail + label{display:none}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{background:#000066}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before{content: '✓'}
input:hover + label{background:rgba(0,0,102,0.5)}
input[type=checkbox]{
  width     : 2em;
  margin    : 0;
  padding   : 0;
  font-size : 1em;
  opacity   : 0;}
```

```html
<button id = "emailer" class='emailer' ></button> 
    <input class="radioEmail" id="option" type="checkbox" name="field" value="option"> 
    <label for="option"></label> 

    <input class="radioEmail" id="option2" type="checkbox" name="field" value="option"> 
    <label for="option2"></label>
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/silverstarfy/djhjb4du/)

Comment: Please at least clean up your code with some formatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `radios` variable contains a collection of the radio labels:

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll(".radioEmail+label");
```

When a label is clicked, the `click` event is triggered *before* the input value actually changes.

I would normally recommend putting inputs *within* their labels.  However,you have a lot of `input + label` CSS that would break, and I don't know what other code you might have that could also break.

A quick solution given your current HTML and CSS would be to check the radio buttons within a [**setTimeout()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout):

```
radios[i].addEventListener('click',
  function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var checkingChecks = document.querySelectorAll(".radioEmail:checked").length;
      if (checkingChecks > 0) {
        checker.className = "confirm";
      } else {
        checker.className = "cancel";
      }
    });
  }
)
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xa8w0fqh/)

Comment: This worked for me! thank you so much for the info on the order of the label vs input click events. I honestly had no clue about the order.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="the_box" />

 $(document).ready(function(){ 
    %('#the_box').on('change', function(){ 
       if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            //checkbox is checked, do something
           }

   })


})
```